# MATLAB *.pcm to *.wav converting

Tags: matlab

How can I convert `*.pcm` audio file to `*.wav` audio File in MATLAB-Code?
I just need to insert a header, but how it is work?
Thank you very much!

Comment: one way is to use ffmpeg from within matlab.
[Can ffmpeg convert audio from raw PCM to WAV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986279/can-ffmpeg-convert-audio-from-raw-pcm-to-wav)

Comment: Thanks, and this ffmpeg is a external script?

Comment: Can you try AUDIOREAD to read in the file and AUDIOWRITE to write out WAV files?

Comment: `Error using audioread (line 88)
File could not be read due to an unexpected error. Reason: Unable to pop the top most message from the bus

Error in readdata3 (line 49)
[y,Fs] = audioread('15_10_2018_110044.pcm');`

Comment: I don't find a function to read pcm-File in MATLAB - to use "audioread" is not possible -  **The file type is not supported** to use 
`fid = fopen ('15_10_2018_110044.pcm','r');`
is possible, but i dont know, how can I exploring this File! Can you help me please?

Comment: Maybe, another issue - i,m saving a *.PCM with QTCreator AudioRecorder. Maybe, I can chose another recording codec, to able to use Audioread with MATLAB!?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify it, I'm assuming you are using Matlab 2018b, so I will point you to the most recent documentation about [audioread](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html):

[image: audioread]

As you can see, **PCM is not on the supported format list**.

You should try to look if you can parameter your AudioRecorder to record your audio to another format within the ones in the supported list: .wav, .ogg, .flac, .au, .aif, .aifc, mp3, .mp4...

---

An alternative option, without using `audioread`, would be to import pcm data like any other data file, then convert it to 16 bit wav. I assume sample rate is 44100 Hz.

```
fid = fopen('audioFile.pcm');                 % Open raw pcm file
audio = int16(fread(fid, Inf, 'int16'));      % Convert data into 16 bit
fclose(fid);                                  % Close pcm file
audiowrite('audioFile.wav', audio, 44100,'BitsPerSample', 16); % Write wav
```

Comment: Hei Bebs, thank you, I have read a MATLAB documentation. The Problem is to create one of this format with QT Creator - for example FLAC. Do you have example code for it, just change 'setCodec' from PCM to FLAC don't works

Comment: @Fracture, that would be another question, not related with Matlab, but with QT Creator. I would recommend you to close this question, and write a new one with appropriate title and tags: it will increase the chances of having an answer.